# problems installing leap motion orion

Tags: software-installation

So i have some issues installing Leap Motion Orion. I'm trying to install it as follows:

```
cd Downloads/
cd Leap_Motion_Installer_Packages_release_public_linux/
sudo dpkg --install Leap-2.3.1+31549-x64.deb
```

Error message:

```
dpkg --install Leap-2.3.1+31549-x64.deb 
(Reading database ... 280274 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack Leap-2.3.1+31549-x64.deb ...
Failed to stop leapd.service: Unit leapd.service not loaded.
Unpacking leap (2.3.1+31549) over (2.3.1+31549) ...
removed '/etc/init.d/leapd'
Setting up leap (2.3.1+31549) ...
Leap Motion installed under /usr/bin and /usr/sbin
Failed to start leapd.service: Unit leapd.service not found.
dpkg: error processing package leap (--install):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 5
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
leap
```

Comment: Do you have /etc/init.d/leapd?

Comment: I don't think so no. Can you explain to me what it is?

Comment: In init.d, there is scripts that is used by the System V init program. The scripts are the bash script file that contains events like start, stop, etc. and what to do inside these events

Comment: Yes i have the /etc/init.d/leapd script

Answer (score 8):

Leap is still set up for upstart, and the recent move from upstart to systemd make some packages like Leap failed to install.

Follow the steps below:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/leapd.service
sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/system/leapd.service /etc/systemd/system/leapd.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo dpkg --install Leap-2.3.1+31549-x64.deb
```

leapd.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=LeapMotion Daemon
After=syslog.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/leapd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After installation, you can see:

```
Check Leap Motion daemon with: service leapd status 
Open the Leap Motion GUI with: LeapControlPanel 
See /usr/share/Leap/README.linux for more information
```

[Source](http://blog.csdn.net/philthinker/article/details/73381884)